# Android Studio 2.2, Gradle build fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I just upgraded to Android Studio 2.2 and I can no longer build my project because the Gradle build always fails with multiple `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`

From my research, it seems this could have more to do with my operating system (OSX El Capitan) than with Gradle itself. However, I have attempted several workarounds with no success.

My studio.vmoptions file looks like this:

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

`ulimit -a` gives me the following:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

I've tried increasing my max user processes to no avail. Is anyone else having this issue? My current JDK is 1.8.0_102

Comment: Set maxheap true in menifest.

Comment: @Bansal I believe that's to enable the application to use a larger heap, but my problem happens way before I can even compile my app. My error happens during the Gradle sync in the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same issue with my project which can be built without problem before upgrading.

Switched back to gradle 2.1.3 from 2.2.0 fixed the problem.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be a problem with Gradle 2.1.4. There's currentlly a thread on the AOSP issue tracker. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=223038

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into the same wall I did, you may try disabling Instant Run. I had to take these steps to build successfully:
- upgrade to gradle 2.2.3 when prompted
- disable Instant Run in AS preferences
- go back to gradle 2.1.3 in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

go back to gradle 2.1.3 in build.gradle file.

Comment: Your answer does not provide additional info compared to the accepted answer. Please consider improving it or removing it. As it is, it will possibly get removed by revision queues. Thanks.