# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

Recently updated to android 2.2 .

tried opening an existing project. It prompted me to convert, I accepted. The project imported successfully but whenever I tried building, I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I have added :

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

to gradle.properties. Still, it hasn't worked.

Comment: did u go through https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Answer (score 4):

You have a chance to face the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread` whenever the JVM asks for a new thread from the OS. Whenever the underlying OS cannot allocate a new native thread, this OutOfMemoryError will be thrown. The exact limit for native threads is very platform-dependent thus we recommend to find out those limits by running a test similar to the below example. But, in general, the situation causing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread` goes through the following phases:

1. A new Java thread is requested by an application running inside the
   JVM
2. JVM native code proxies the request to create a new native
   thread to the OS The OS tries to create a new native thread which
   requires memory to be allocated to the thread
3. The OS will refuse
   native memory allocation either because the 32-bit Java process size
   has depleted its memory address space – e.g. (2-4) GB process size
   limit has been hit – or the virtual memory of the OS has been fully
   depleted
4. The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native
   thread error is thrown.

Reference: https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Answer (score 0):

> Switched back to gradle 2.1.3 from 2.2.0 fixed the problem.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599959/android-studio-2-2-gradle-build-fails-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-t).